# Accessing cell prototype when adding multiple tableviews

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm working with an app where there are an `unknown number of tableViews`, created using a for loop.  The problem is an issue when aligning `cellReuseIdentifier` with the cell prototype.

I get a crash with the error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier Cell0 - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'.

My code looks like this:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var inviteArray: [(greetingText: String, greetingArray: [String])] = []    // we don't know up front the size of the inviteArray or the sizes of the greetingArray's
    var tableViewArray: [UITableView] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var tableReference = 0
        for invite in inviteArray {
            let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
            self.tableViewArray.append(myTableView)
            myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            myTableView.delegate = self
            myTableView.dataSource = self
            myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell\(tableReference)")
            addSubview(myTableView)
            tableReference = tableReference + 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count = inviteArray[0].greetingArray.count
        for (index, table) in tableViewArray.enumerated() {
            if tableView == table {
                count = inviteArray[index].greetingArray.count
            }
        }
        return count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell0", for: indexPath)
        var cell = UITableViewCell?    // replacing the variable declaration line above solved this
        for (index, table) in tableViewArray.enumerated() {
            if tableView == table {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell\(index)", for: indexPath)
                cell.textLabel?.text = inviteArray[index].greetingArray[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.default
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        return cell
    }
}
```

Using a tableViewArray to capture the multiple tableviews appears to be a dead-end, does someone know another way of doing this?

Comment: please check out my answer and mark it if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Go to Storyboard, click on the prototype cell on the Tableviwe and give it the same identifier that you are dequeueing, the error says

> 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell0 - must register a nib
>   or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a
>   storyboard'.

in your case the identifier should be "Cell0"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell
    for (index, table) in tableViewArray.enumerated() {
        if tableView == table {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell\(index)", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = inviteArray[index].greetingArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.default
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    return cell
}
```

Comment: In this case Tobi, I have ‘Cell0’, ‘Cell1’, ... ‘CellN’, and cells are created programmatically, so that does not work

Comment: to dequeue a cell, the cell prototype should exist in the first place to draw them on the UI dequeue is redrawing the same cell when user  scroll away from it to limit the number of cells in the background for more memory efficient, so you are basically using the same cell  and redraw it over and over again so giving a dynamic id for each cell then you have to implement each single on of the id's you are using in the SB

Comment: can you provide more info, about why you need multiple cell id's

Comment: I have an unknown number of tables (this depends on the users’ responses), each with their own table sources. If you look at my sample code, you can see this (inviteArray)

Comment: well delegates are 1-1 relationship so you need to know what table is being populated by the delegate ill edit my answer and try it out an tell me what happens

Answer (score 0):

replacing the variable declaration in the edited post solved the issue